# Kerberos Authentication always unsuccessful

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have this code for capturing user credentials:

```
string domain = Domain.GetComputerDomain().ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(domain);
            string username =
                new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
                    .Identity.Name;

            Console.WriteLine(username);

            Console.Write("Password: ");
            //there are far better ways to get a hidden password this was just an easy way as it's irrelevant to the point of the application, will improve
            string password = null;
            while (true)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    break;
                password += key.KeyChar;
            }
```

And this method for authenticating with Kerberos:

```
private static bool ValidateCredentialsKerberos(string username, string password, string domain)
        {
            var credentials
              = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

            var id = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(domain);

            using (var connection = new LdapConnection(id, credentials, AuthType.Kerberos))
            {
                connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
                connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true;

                try
                {
                    connection.Bind();
                }
                catch (LdapException lEx)
                {
                    if (ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE == lEx.ErrorCode)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    throw;
                }

            }
            return true;

        }
```

It always throws false as incorrect credentials despite the credentials being correct. The output into the console is as follows:

Domain.net
Domain/user
Password

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;` returns the username in DOMAIN\username format, whereas LdapConnection expects to see just the username (you are already sending the domain as another parameter).

You can use `Environment.UserName` to get just the username.

Another issue is that the `ErrorCode` you are checking against isn't correct. You'll get "The supplied credential is invalid." message from the DC (error code 49).

(By the way, you didn't have to create a new `WindowsPrincipal`, you could have just use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`)